# Rails 3: Adding a params value to a link_to call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built a very simple internal messaging system inside my application, i want to add a link to each user profile page where the logged in user can click on the link to send the other user which profile they are viewing a message.

messages is nested under users, so new message page would be `/users/1/messages/new`

so i have: `<%= link_to 'Send Message', new_user_message_path(current_user) %>` how can i add a params values to the link with the user id and name of of the user he/she is viewing (object is called `@user`) so the href would look something like this: `/users/1/messages/new?to_id=3&to_name=somename`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'Send Message', new_user_message_path(current_user, :to_id => 3) %>
```